# @bot.event in a cog discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I was wondering if it is possible to use @bot.event
in a cog for discord.py. I have tried doing

```
@self.bot.event
async def on_member_join(self, ctx, member):
    channel = discord.utils.get(member.guild.channels, name='general')
    await channel.send("hello")
```

in my cog class, but I get the error

```
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

even though I define self.bot in my __init __.

Is there a different way of doing bot.event in cogs, or is it just not possible?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To register an event from a [new-style cog](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/cogs.html), you must use the [`commands.Cog.listener`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Cog.listener) decorator.  Below is mental's example converted to the new style:

```
from discord.ext import commands

class Events(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Ready!')
        print('Logged in as ---->', self.bot.user)
        print('ID:', self.bot.user.id)

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        print(message)

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Events(bot))
```

Answer (score 4):

I do not reccomend qspitzers answer since this is not a sensible way of moving your events to a cog and the answer may throw some unknown/unexpected exceptions.

Instead do something like this.

```
from discord.ext import commands

class Events:
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Ready!')
        print('Logged in as ---->', self.bot.user)
        print('ID:', self.bot.user.id)

    async def on_message(self, message):
        print(message)

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Events(bot))
```

Keep in mind that to place an event inside a cog you do not need a decorator for it. Also the events inside the cog do not overide the default events and these events will be stored in `bot.extra_events`.

Comment: Surely the Events class must draw from commands.Cog as in Patrick Haugh's answer?

Comment: This stopped working in v1.0 and later. Refer to Patrick Haugh's answer below.

Answer (score -1):

So, I figured out a way to get this to work. What I did was I created a new function and passed it the bot variable from the setup function. I then created a background task of the new function, and had @bot.event running in that. The code is

```
def xyz(bot):
    @bot.event
    async def on_member_join(member):
        print("ABC")

def setup(bot):
    bot.loop.create_task(xyz(bot))
    bot.add_cog(cogClass(bot))
```

in case anyone did not understand my explanation

EDIT:
this is a bad way of doing things. use mental's way instead