# Discord @bot.event in cog

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I tried to use [the example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48090852/11171078) of *Mental* for events in cogs but i'm lost. I can't figured it out how to triger the event in my main.py file. Where the `bot.extra_events` goes?

Here is my script :

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord
import sys, traceback

startup_extensions = ["cog"]

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?')


@bot.event
async def on_ready():  

    if __name__ == '__main__':
            for extension in startup_extensions:
                try:
                    bot.load_extension(extension)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f'Failed to load extension {extension}.', file=sys.stderr)
                    traceback.print_exc()
    print(f'Successfully logged in and booted...!')





bot.run("TOKEN")
```

I'm using the v0.16.12.
Thanks, it's my first python project

Comment: `bot.extra_events` is taken care of for you in `load_extension`, there's no reason for you to interact with it directly.  The `Events.on_message` event should trigger whenever a message is sent that the bot can see, and that message should print to stdout of wherever you're running the bot from.

Comment: Ok you're right, I tried again and it works. Thanks